# How to push tracking event into serviceWorker?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, service-worker

is it possible track the click action in `serviceWorker`, here is a snippet of `notificationclick` event listener.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
var url = event.notification.data.url;
event.notification.close();
event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(url));});
```

GTM Event :

`dataLayer.push({'event' : 'notificationClick'});`

I believe that the datalayer is already in the DOM which `serviceWorker` could not access, but isn't their any workaround to track the web push notification?

Comment: Could you clarify the question?

Comment: i mean isn't their any way to use GTM into service worker?

Answer (score 2):

Make a fetch request from `notificationclick` event and there you write code to track clicks on notifications.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
    .then(function(subscription) {
        // send update to server
        fetch('trackClick.php?subscriptionId='+subscriptionId)
        catch(function(err) {
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: yes i think about this solution, but i don't think that  GTM has a PHP SDK.